# Typescrpt regular expression extract x,y locations

Tags: regex, typescript

I'm using Typescript and was wondering if I can use regular expressions to do the following.

input that comes in a string

`"(0,1)(1,2)(3,1)"`

There are quite a few validations which I need to do in this

1. Every individual value should be a number.
2. Each number cannot be larger than a variable value `x` provided at runtime.
3. If all the validations pass I want to get the matches out in an array and strip out the paranthesis.

Is this something possible with regular expressions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a js question - anyway you can achieve your desire solution with `regexp` and extra logic:

```
export const validate = (input: string, maxValue: number) => {
    const match = input.match(/\((\d+),(\d+)\)\((\d+),(\d+)\)\((\d+),(\d+)\)/);
    if (match) {
        const results = match.slice(1, 7);
        const pass = results.every(item => Number(item) < maxValue);
        if (pass) {
            return results.map(n => Number(n));
        }
    }

    return false;
};

validate('(1,1)(1,2)(3,1)', 3); // false 
validate('(1,1)(1,2)(3,1)', 5); // [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1 ]
validate('(1,1)(1,2)(3,1s)', 5); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for this, what does `match.slice(1, 7)` do ?

Comment: string `match` will return you an array with all the `capturing groups` if the `regexp` come without `g` flag - the first index is always the all match - 1-7 is the results of each `catpure group` - you can read on it more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)